# pandas groupby not using for loop (how to make smart)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series, pandas-groupby, series

Suppose you have a pandas Series like this.

`a = pd.Series(range(31),index = pd.date_range('2018-01-01','2018-01-31',freq='D'))`

If you want to make groupby dataframe with multi index like this

`data
           date

2018-01-01 2018-01-01     0
           2018-01-02     1
           2018-01-03     2
           2018-01-04     3
           2018-01-05     4
2018-01-02 2018-01-02     1
           2018-01-03     2
           2018-01-04     3
           2018-01-05     4
           2018-01-06     5
2018-01-03 2018-01-03     2
           2018-01-04     3
           2018-01-05     4
           2018-01-06     5
           2018-01-07     6
.....`

This data shows that in the first level Multi index, it shows the original date time index. And in the second level, we cut the date into 5 days. 
For example, if first level is 2018-01-01, second level is 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-05. 
If first level is 2018-01-15, second level is 2018-01-15 to 2018-01-19 and data is 14, 15, 16, 17, 18.

How Can I make this DataFrame or Series without any loop?

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
import datetime as dt
first = np.repeat(a.index.values,5)
second = [ i + np.timedelta64(j,'D') for i in a.index for j in range(5)]
arrays = [first, second]
print(np.shape(second))
d=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('date1', 'date2')))
```

**Output (`d.head()`)**

```
                       value
date1      date2            
2018-01-01 2018-01-01    0.0
           2018-01-02    1.0
           2018-01-03    2.0
           2018-01-04    3.0
           2018-01-05    4.0
2018-01-02 2018-01-02    1.0
           2018-01-03    2.0
           2018-01-04    3.0
           2018-01-05    4.0
           2018-01-06    5.0
```

Comment: So for loop is essential for making first and second. Right?